# Django filters, got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm using: http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html
and I have a problem with this code:

```
class BasicFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = []

class SiteFilter(BasicFilter):
    site = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Site.objects.all(), help_text=''
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        super(BrowserFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta(ReportFilter.Meta):
        fields = ['site']
```

And when I'm using this:

```
site_filter = SiteFilter(user='test')
```

I've got:

> **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Comment: Are you sure you want to call `super(BrowserFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`? I guess it should be `super(SiteFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ernest Ten. Looks like first thing you need to try is to change

```
super(BrowserFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

to

```
super(SiteFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake while copying. I have: super(SiteFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: @Jeremiasz1 and what prints `print kwargs`?